# Find duplicate ID's with different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that contain UserID's and Departments. UserID's can belong to several departments so their combo makes it unique.

However I have been trying to query trying to find where the UserID belongs to either one of two departments (hr or customer).

```
SELECT UserId, Dept, COUNT(*) Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

However this still brings back duplicates if a UserId has both departments I guess because the combo makes it a unique record.

What I get back is this

```
UserID | Department     |  Total  
1            hr              1  
2            customer        1  
3            customer        1  
1            customer        1  
3            hr              1
```

But what I am trying to get back is this

```
UserID | Department     |  Total  
2            customer        1
```

Where any instances of UserId belonging to both departments are not included only if they belong to one or the other.

Comment: What do you expect for customer 1 or 3?

Comment: That query is not valid and should have generated an error since Dept is neither in the `GROUP BY` definition nor grouped

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
select t1.UserId, Dept, t2.Total
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) Total
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY UserID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the above query will run as Dept is not in group by clause and also count comparsion cannot be in that way.
Coming to your issue:

```
Select userid, Dept 
from #temp
where userid in (Select userid from (Select userid,count(*) 'C' 
from #temp group by userid ) u where u.c=1)
```

I do not think you require count as it is always `1`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT UserId,   COUNT(distinct Dept) Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(distinct Dept) = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps provide some explanation for your answer would help the OP greatly

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
select UserId, Dept
FROM Mytable where UserId in
(
   SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) Total
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY UserID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

If you add the Dept column in your Group by you will always retrieve all the combinations.
So you have to select all users with only one Dept and then retrieve the additional informations

There is maybe syntax errors because I am usually working with oracle but I think the concept is correct

Answer (score 0):

This will select users in 'hr' that do not have id's in 'customer' and then users in 'customer' that do not have ids in 'hr'.
I didn't include count on purpose as it can always only be one.

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] T WHERE Department = 'hr' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].UserID =T.UserID AND Department = 'customer') UNION 
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] T WHERE Department = 'customer' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyTable].UserID =T.UserID AND Department = 'hr')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `COUNT (*)` at the end.

Try this:

```
SELECT UserId, Dept, COUNT(*) Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(UserId) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fake question because you can't use Dept in this query.
I'm don't understand why author doesn't explain us about any compiler warnings and tells us some results of this query.

but you can yse this way if you really want to get some result:

```
SELECT UserId, min(Dept) as Dept
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```